# spdiags() in MATLAB into Python

Tags: python, matlab, function, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am trying to translate a MATLAB implementation into a Python 3 implementation. I've found a function, spdiags(), that I do not understand, and am also not sure how to translate it into Python 3.

The MATLAB documentation on the function is here:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spdiags.html

The Scipy documentation on an identically named function is here:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.spdiags.html

What does the MATLAB function do, and is there a Python implementation of the same return available?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Octave (MATLAB alternative), the example in its documentation:

```
octave:7> x = spdiags (reshape (1:12, 4, 3), [-1 0 1], 5, 4);
octave:8> full(x)  # display as a full or dense matrix
ans =    
    5   10    0    0
    1    6   11    0
    0    2    7   12
    0    0    3    8
    0    0    0    4
```

The actual values that are stored in `x` are:

```
x =
Compressed Column Sparse (rows = 5, cols = 4, nnz = 11 [55%])
  (1, 1) ->  5
  (2, 1) ->  1
  (1, 2) ->  10
  (2, 2) ->  6
  (3, 2) ->  2
  (2, 3) ->  11
  (3, 3) ->  7
  (4, 3) ->  3
  (3, 4) ->  12
  (4, 4) ->  8
  (5, 4) ->  4
```

The equivalent `scipy.sparse` expression:

```
In [294]: x = sparse.spdiags(np.arange(1,13).reshape(3,4), [-1, 0, 1], 5, 4)
In [295]: x.A   # display as normal numpy array
Out[295]: 
array([[ 5, 10,  0,  0],
       [ 1,  6, 11,  0],
       [ 0,  2,  7, 12],
       [ 0,  0,  3,  8],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  4]])

In [296]: x
Out[296]: 
<5x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 11 stored elements (3 diagonals) in DIAgonal format>
```

This use the `dia` format, but it easy to transfrom to `csc` (equivalent to the Octave format) with `x.tocsc()`.

To see the same coordinates and values, we can use the `dok` format (a dictionary subclass):

```
In [299]: dict(x.todok())
Out[299]: 
{(0, 1): 10,
 (1, 2): 11,
 (3, 2): 3,
 (0, 0): 5,
 (3, 3): 8,
 (2, 1): 2,
 (2, 3): 12,
 (4, 3): 4,
 (2, 2): 7,
 (1, 0): 1,
 (1, 1): 6}
```

Same values, adjusting for the 0 based indexing.

In both cases, the diagonal values come from a matrix:

```
octave:10> reshape(1:12, 4, 3)
ans =
    1    5    9
    2    6   10
    3    7   11
    4    8   12

In [302]: np.arange(1,13).reshape(3,4)
Out[302]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])
```

Octave/MATLAB arrange values by column, `numpy` by row, hence the different `reshape`.  **The `numpy` matrix is the transpose of the MATLAB equivalent.**

Note that `9` has been omitted from both (4 items mapped on to a 3 element diagonal).

The other argument is a list of diagonals to set, `[-1,0,1]`, and final shape `(5,4)`.

Most of the differences in arguments have to do the basic differences between MATLAB and numpy.  The other difference is that MATLAB has only one sparse matrix representation, scipy has a half dozen.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this answer can only scratch the surface, but:

For matrices, there's different storage formats. Of course, there's the most intuitive "row after row" and "column after column" formats, but there's also formats for matrices with only a few non-zero entries, which of course save a lot of memory (and might save a lot of CPU) if used correctly.

So, these diagonal sparse matrices are such a case of a specially stored matrix in matlab; If you don't care about the computational advantages, just use `diag`, which is functionally 100% equivalent (but doesn't generate sparse matrices).

The existence of sparse matrix storage is a Matlab feature, and scipy does in fact (I'm actually surprised by that) have that feature, too. So use the scipy method if it fits your needs!

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution for that, its really easy try this and you will get the same answer from MATLAB and python, by python u have sometimes to change the Format of the Inputs.

so try this:

```
sparse.spdiags(your_Array.T, diags, m, n)
```